# Wireless Adapter Turning Off Second Monitor

Tags: wireless-networking, power-supply

I am having issues with my wireless adapter and my second monitor. When I enable the wireless adapter, my second monitor decides to turn off (no display, it is still powered) or just flicker on and off. I thought it might have been a power supply issue but I have just gone from a 450W PSU to 600W (borrowed from a friend). I am now using a 500W PSU. Each PSU has done the same thing.

It works completely fine up until the Windows login screen. I am able to access the BIOS with this screen.

System Information:

- Windows 10
- Wireless Adapter: TP-Link WN881ND (Connected via PCIe)
- GPU: Asus GTX 960 2GB
- CPU: i5-6400 @ 2.7GHz
- Motherboard: H110M Pro VD

Here is my [DxDiag file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2c9kcikreqtjb0r/DxDiag.txt?dl=0) as well. I really don't know where to begin with this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, this is just wierd, and interesting. Maybe try swapping the port the wireless adaptor is on, and seeing if it does it with an extension?

Comment: Yeah I am a bit stuck to be honest. I only have one slot available so I am unable to do that. What do you mean by extension?

Comment: That's extremely bizarre. I can't really think how it could be driver related, but perhaps try a later Atheros driver from [here](https://www.atheros-drivers.com/qualcomm-atheros-download-drivers-nr-309-with-code-1931.html) and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Just gave those drivers a go and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Ahh, I assumed it was USB for some reason

Comment: Is the screen properly shielded? Do you get similar issues if you hold an active mobile phone near it?

Comment: That seems to be the issue. Do you have any idea on how I go about shielding this? Is it something I can do myself or will I have to purchase something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my monitor was interfering with my wireless card. I was using a cheap adapter from ebay which was not shielded. To solve the issue, I placed aluminium foil around the adapter only covering pretty much the entire thing.